# Displaying data from database from Controller to View using jQuery AJAX request CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am having a problem in fetching data from database using jQuery AJAX as json datatype I have read and tried JSON.parse in jQuery but it did not work. All I am returning in `console.log(data)` is `object` and the data from database in object but I don't know how to show it on view. Any suggestions please.

Here is my Controller.

```
  function fetch(){
                $data_fetch     = array(
                    'id'        => $this->input->post('txt_id')
                    );
                $data['records'] = $this->form_model->fetch_model($data_fetch);
        $results    = json_encode($data);

            $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
            $this->output->set_output($results);
        }
```

Here is my jQuery AJAX

```
$.ajax({
            type    : 'POST',
            url     :  base_url + 'index.php/form_controller/fetch',
            data    : {txt_id : id },
            dataType : 'JSON',
            success : function(data){
                // var re = JSON.parse(data);
                // var re = $.parseJSON(data);
                // var data = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data.name);
                console.log(data);

            },
            error   : function(data){
                console.log('erronr in fetch');
            }
        });
```

The `data.name` is showing `undefined` in alert. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSON.parse` the variable data is already a JSON, so just use it as a you would with any other JSON.

Comment: I am beginer in jquery can show me a little example bro... :)

Comment: any suggestion how should i alert name field from database like i am currently doing now but it is returning undefined.

Comment: Sorry for not answering yesterday, it was 2 AM here. Well, I think I know where your problem is... instead of using `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');` and `$this->output->set_output($results);` try just an echo of the $results variable like this: 
`echo $results;` It should now work.

Comment: k i will give it a try.